# OData services in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odata

I have an O-Data service, and I already consumed it in ASP.Net project using VS 2012

Now i want to use an ASP.Net User Control to handle CRUD operations for this odata service automatically.

I hope to find a user control like GridView that allow me to :

1. Display the data from the odata service.
2. Add new records.
3. Update an existing one.
4. Delete an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, but Kendo UI/Telerik's MVC Grid probably the most prevalent that has built in support:
http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnetmvcteam/posts/10-12-16/binding-telerik-grid-for-asp-net-mvc-to-odata.aspx
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Personally, I would recommend to do your own CRUD operations, or use something like Datatables http://www.datatables.net/ and write your own adapter to run between.